# Multiple keycodes emitted for single keypress

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

My goal is to remap a key called `sysrq` on my keyboard to be `Super_R`.

I know I need to first find the keycode that corresponds to the physical key that is being pressed and then remap it using `xmodmap -e "keycode nnn = Super_R"` where `nnn` is the keycode found whilst running `xev` and pressing the physical key.

However the issue I have is that whilst running `xev | grep keycode` and pressing the `sysrq` key on my keyboard I get *two* keycodes being emitted.

```
$ xev | grep keycode

state 0x0, keycode 64 (keysym 0xffe9, Alt_L), same_screen YES,
state 0x8, keycode 64 (keysym 0xffe9, Alt_L), same_screen YES,
state 0x0, keycode 64 (keysym 0xffe9, Alt_L), same_screen YES,
state 0x8, keycode 107 (keysym 0xff15, Sys_Req), same_screen YES,
state 0x8, keycode 107 (keysym 0xff15, Sys_Req), same_screen YES,
state 0x8, keycode 64 (keysym 0xffe9, Alt_L), same_screen YES,
```

The `Sys_Req` key code makes sense - one for key press down and the other for key press up. But it has the `Alt_L` keycode peppered in there at the same time. How do I stop that with a view to eventually remapping the `sysrq` physical key to emit the `Super_R` keycode?

```
$ showkey --keycodes

keycode  56 press
keycode  56 release
keycode  56 press
keycode  99 press
keycode  99 release
keycode  56 release
```

```
kernel: 5.13.0-27-generic #29~20.04.1-Ubuntu
os: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
gnome: 3.36.8
window system: X11
laptop: starlabs starbook mk v
```

Comment: Which supported release of Ubuntu are you using? X Windows or Wayland? What's the model of the keyboard? Have you checked the manufacturer's (of the keyboard) web site? Read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting

Comment: Updated question with some more information. I've contacted the manufacturer and they don't know how to help here.

Comment: Thanks @Quasímodo I've updated with the output. For a single press of my `sysrq` key I get multiple codes press and release. What does that mean? I'm out of luck?